# Struct members are not updating through pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am struggling to understand pointers to structs, so I wrote a sample code with a few print statements.

```
struct Student {
      uint32_t id;
      uint8_t marks[8];
      int32_t credit;
};

struct Student jacob;
struct Student *adam = &jacob;
struct Student mary = *adam;
mary.marks[3] = 80;
jacob.marks[3] = 75;
adam->marks[3] = 67;  

printf("jacob: %d\n", jacob);
printf("&jacob: %d\n", &jacob);
printf("adam: %d\n", adam);
printf("*adam: %d\n", *adam);
printf("mary: %d\n", mary);
printf("mary.marks[3]: %d\n", mary.marks[3]);
```

The output is:

```
jacob: 4195856
&jacob: -436012784 
adam: -436012784
*adam: 4195856
mary: 4195856 
mary.marks[3]: 80
```

Why is the value of `mary.marks[3]` 80? From what I understand, `mary` is indirectly pointing to `struct jacob` since `adam` is pointing to the address of `jacob`. So the line `adam->marks[3] = 67` would change the value of `mary.marks[3]` since they are pointing to the same location.

Could someone please help me understand why the value of `mary.marks[3]` remains the same?

Comment: "mary is indirectly pointing". That can't be true. `mary` is not a pointer. `mary` contains a *copy* of what `adam` points to.

Comment: You've not initialized the contents of `jacob`, so what you copy (when assigning `*adam` to `mary`) is undefined.  You should print addresses properly.  You shouldn't pass `jacob` to `printf()` (or `*adam`, or `mary`).

Comment: p.s. For future reference, you should provide a complete example which we can compile. In particular, you are missing `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, the statement `struct Student jacob;` creates space for one copy of the student structure (either on the stack or in memory, depending, but doesn't matter to the answer).

The statement `struct Student *adam = &jacob;` makes adam a pointer to jacob.

The statement `struct Student mary = *adam;` copies the uninitialized data from what adam points to (jacob) to new space allocated for mary.

It's important that you understand that jacob and mary are allocated space. adam is a pointer to jacob.  But when you say mary.marks[3]=80, you're putting a value in the thing "mary" whereas the thing "jacob" is unchanged.

You then write to `jacob.marks[3]` and afterwards overwrite that by using `adam->marks[3]`.

When you printf an address to something you should use %p.  When you printf a structure with %d, C is just looking dumbly at the memory "as if" it were an integer.  In the line where you say `struct Student mary = *adam;` you are copying the (as yet uninitialized) memory containing jacob into the newly allocated memory for mary.  This is why the printf is the same.  If you printf &mary, you'll find that it is not the same memory as jacob or adam.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
struct Student *adam = &jacob;
```

will invoke undefined behavior because`jacob` is declared only and it's member are not initialized.

Also using wrong specifier for a data type in `printf` will lead to undefined behavior of a program. You should also note that struct can't be passed to `printf`.

Now changing your code a little bit

```
struct Student {
        uint32_t id;
        uint8_t marks[3];
        int32_t credit;
    };

int main(void)
{
    struct Student jacob = {0,{0},0};
    struct Student *adam = &jacob;
    struct Student mary = *adam;
    mary.marks[3] = 80;
    jacob.marks[3] = 75;
    adam->marks[3] = 67;

    printf("mary.marks[3]: %d\n", mary.marks[3]);
}
```

Now `jacob` is initialized, initialising a `struct Student` pointer with its value is legal. Now, `adam` points to `jacob` and `mary` is initialized with a *copy of `jacob`* (any changes to the members of `jacob` will not been seen in `mary`).
In `printf` you are printing `mary.marks[3]` which has the value `80`. These statements

```
jacob.marks[3] = 75;
adam->marks[3] = 67;
```

will have no effect on `mary`. Print `jacob.marks[3]` or `adam->marks[3]` and you will see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Because `mary` is not a pointer, when you assigned `*adam` to `mary` you just copied the value of what `adam` points to, so what `mary` holds is not what is pointed to by `adam`; that's why trying to change the value of `*adam` isn't making any changes in `mary`'s value.

Answer (score 1):

You have two struct variables of type `student` and one struct pointer of type `student`.

> a) `jacob` is uninitialized and pointer `*adam` is pointing to jacob.
>
> b) then you are copying `jacob` to `mary` via pointer reference `adam`.
>
> c) `jacob` and `mary` are two different addresses; each has their own copy
>   of data.
>
> d) once you modify `mary.mary[3]`, it will be updated only in `mary`
>   not in `jacob`.

```
mary.marks[3] = 80;
```

is the last updated value so that will be printed.

```
jacob.marks[3] = 75;  //direct
adam->marks[3] = 67;  //via pointer to the same variable
```

Both updating to the same location. You are overwriting onto:

```
jacob.marks[3]
```

Also follow the suggestions from comments.